# Terraform - Azure Windows VM winrm connection issue

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, winrm, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create windows azure VM, copy some file and run some  simple command on that VM using terraform script.
Problem is : I am able to create VM but not able to connect via winrm.

```
provider "azurerm" {

  subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}    
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "cmTFVnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "South India"
  resource_group_name = "cservice"
}    
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "cmTFSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = "cservice"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}    
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "publicip" {

    name                         = "cmTFPublicIP"
    location                     = "South India"
    resource_group_name          = "cservice"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
 }    
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
    name                = "cmTFNSG"
    location            = "South India"
    resource_group_name = "cservice"

    security_rule {
        name                       = "SSH"
        priority                   = 340
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "22"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    security_rule {  
    name                       = "winrm"  
    priority                   = 1010  
    direction                  = "Inbound"  
    access                     = "Allow"  
    protocol                   = "Tcp"  
    source_port_range          = "*"  
    destination_port_range     = "5985"  
    source_address_prefix      = "*"  
    destination_address_prefix = "*"  
  }  
  security_rule {   
    name                       = "winrm-out"  
    priority                   = 100  
    direction                  = "Outbound"  
    access                     = "Allow"  
    protocol                   = "*"  
    source_port_range          = "*"  
    destination_port_range     = "5985"  
    source_address_prefix      = "*"  
    destination_address_prefix = "*"  
  }         
}    
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "cmNIC"
  location            = "South India"
  resource_group_name = "cservice"
 network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id}"
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "compilerNICConfg"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
   public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.id}"
  }
}
 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "cmTFVM"
  location              = "South India"
  resource_group_name   = "cservice"
 network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.nic.id}"]
 vm_size            = "Standard_D2s_v3"

   storage_image_reference 
  {
    id =  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
    storage_os_disk {
    name          = "cmOsDisk"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
    create_option = "FromImage"

  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "test"
    admin_password = "test@123"
  }
   os_profile_windows_config {
        enable_automatic_upgrades = "true"
        provision_vm_agent ="true"
        winrm = {  
                  protocol = "http"  
        }
   }
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
     connection   = {
     type        = "winrm"
     user        = "test"
     password    = "test@123"
     agent       = "false"
     https    = false
     insecure = true
    } 
    inline = [
      "cd..",
      "cd..",
      "cd docker",
      "mkdir test"
    ]
  }
 }
```

VM is created successfully but not able to connect by WINRM
but I am getting following error in "remote-exec":

> azurerm_virtual_machine.vm: timeout - last error: unknown error Post
>   http://:5985/wsman: dial tcp :5985: connectex: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond.
>                       or http response error: 401 - invalid content type

Comment: We need more information in order to help... Such the code samples, error messages, docs you are following, things you have tried

Comment: Can you provide what you have done and which document you follow and what is the most important thing you want to know? Just give more details.

Comment: Any more update?

Comment: till getting the same issue. Is there any other way to copy the file to VM using terraform script. basically it is deployment script, we do not want user interaction pop in it

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Windows Azure VM, the WINRM is not configured by default. So if you want to connect the VM through the WINRM, you should configure the WINRM after the VM creation time, or in the creation time.

You can follow the steps in [Configure WinRM after virtual machine creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal/virtual-machine/cpp-configure-winrm-after-vm-creation). And you can also configure it in the creation time. There is an example shows that through Azure template. It will also provide a little help. See [Deploys a Windows VM and Configures a WinRM Https listener](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-winrm-windows/).

Comment: Still getting the same issue. Is there any other way to copy the file to VM using terraform script. basically it is deployment script, we do not want user interaction pop in it.

Comment: @ShrutiSijaria Yes, you can use the [VM extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) with a PowerShell script to do it, it's recommended. See the [VM extension in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html). In the PowerShell script, you can use AzCopy or scp as you wish.